# Determine table structure

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I want to create db for anime. This is my ER structure:
https://ibb.co/ctRk8f6

Any tips to improve this?

Every anime has blob for image and relations to brand and episode, each episode may have multiple links and relation to tag.

I wanted to know if this structure is good or should I make separate table for image or any other tip

```sql
CREATE TABLE Brand
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Tag
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Anime
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name INT NOT NULL,
    img INT NOT NULL,
    id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Brand(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Episode
(
    order INT NOT NULL,
    rating INT NOT NULL,
    date INT NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (order, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Anime(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Link
(
    link INT NOT NULL,
    host INT NOT NULL,
    order INT NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (link, order, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (order, id) REFERENCES Episode(order, id)
);

CREATE TABLE TagOfAnime
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Anime(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Tag(id)
);
```

Comment: You should post your structure inline in your question, not as a link - and not as an image.

Comment: the sql create code?

Comment: I have no idea what your "ER" structure is because I didn't click on your link. Post your question with enough detail to allow someone to understand without clicking on links. Include what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

- Why is everything of type `INT`? I would assume that `name` would be a `nvarchar` of some maximum length `nvarchar(200)` perhaps?
- Your `TagOfAnime` table has two columns named `id`. That will not work. If they are references to the primary keys to the `tag` and `Anime` tables, then you should name them as such: `Tag_id` and `Anime_id`
- I would not name a table `Link`. What is it "linking"? I would make it more descriptive.
- In general, add a table if there can be multiple items associated with a single row in another table - as you are doing with the tags for Animes. Otherwise, if the data can appear in additional columns of a single row of the base table, then consolidate your tables to avoid complexity.
  Other than that, ask specific questions where you are stuck and I'm sure someone will jump in to help.